# Centralized data access design logic

Tags: android, service

I am having trouble grasping the correct way to implement a centralized data access for different resources.

I want to have a single class, call it `DataAccess.class` that will call from both a `SQLiteDatabaseHelper.class` and a `ServerAccess.class` depending on what is appropriate when I call it's methods.

I thought extending `DataAccess.class` from a Service was the best approach so I can use ASyncTask for the `ServerAccess.class`. Now I am having doubts. The `DataAccess.class` needs to be accessible by most of the Activities in my Application, and I want it to stop when the Application does.

According to the google developer resources it sounds like a Service is well used for ongoing operations in the background but I am unsure how to handle the life cycle given the scope that I am trying to incorporate. Can I make the Service call `startService()` and `stopService()` internally when I use the `DataAccess.class` methods? Does it make sense to call it every time I access the Service or should this only happen once at the start and stop of the Application?

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Good question.  I think a lot of us have done something similar, but what is the ideal way?

Comment: I would add that communication between Service and Activity does make an all AsyncTask approach look better.  Its easier to manage the callbacks I think.  But how to do this without ending up with a lot of Singletons ....I AsyncTask is more for when you are not using a service. Its to get things off the UI thread. I can tell you I have seen implementation using all async tasks only and no service. So thats really one part of the question is whether to use a service to handle async tasks at all.

Comment: My first inclination was to use service too, but then is issue of two way communication between service and activity and sharing. I am leaning towards all AsyncTask approach is best for handling the events involved. But would like to hear the opinion of others. I would add that just one Facade like DataAccess does not have that many advantages, usually there is more than one facade. Look at Android System Services for example

Comment: Go for Shared Preference instead of Database if your data is  in small amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend

1) Use all AsyncTask based solution because Service - Activity Communication is limited. (Unless of course you need to run something in the background) BUT I would love to hear the counterargument to this, why use a service instead.

2) Don't use just one Facade like DataAccess but make it specific to your app functions (ie sort of like System Services in Android).

3) You should use factories just like Android does to get the DataAcccess object you need. This addresses second part of where you get DataAccess object.  Follow same model as getting and Android System service.

4) Use Content Providers where indicated and manage as indicated in Android docs.

Update: I think these are sort of the Axioms of a good solution.  Not the whole thing.  I will update as we consider this in depth.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think you are on the right track with keeping to your axioms. I was trying to over simplify the interface at the cost creating a bit of a headache!